# Split data separated by pipe from a file perl

Tags: perl

I have a file which i have data pipe seprated having some values 0 ,1 , or some text. Now what i have to do is to read the file line by line and split data seprated by pipe and then if the values of any index is 1 then i have create increment it's value by 1 into a hash so at last i have a hash which will give details how many true values are there in the files.

Below is the example  of data and the name of each value , if the value is 1 then in hash key value will get incremented by 1

```
A B C D E F G    H       I
===========================
0|0|0|1|0|0|ABC|15:44:07|0
0|0|0|1|0|0|ABC|15:44:07|0
0|0|0|0|0|0|ABC|15:44:07|0
0|1|0|0|0|1|ABC|15:44:07|0
```

So final out put will be like below :

```
$finalHash->{D} = 2;
$finalHash->{F} = 1;
$finalHash->{B} = 1;
```

I am able to read the file line by line :

```
 my $final_hash;
 for my $line ( <$ifh> ) {

    my @el = split( /\|/, $line );

    #Now here have to set the value in the hashkey where we will get the 1 value


  }
```

Comment: what's your issue? It seems like you are on the right track. [see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeTung i unable to understand how should i create that hash from the file data and increment the values. I am new in perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `for` to iterate file lines, use `while`. The former might exhaust  memory if the file was very large, as it needs to create a list of all the lines; the latter reads one line at a time.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @column_names = qw( A B C D E F );

my %counts;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @columns = split /\|/;
    for my $i (0 .. $#column_names) {
        ++$counts{ $column_names[$i] } if $columns[$i];
    }
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%counts;

__DATA__
0|0|0|1|0|0|ABC|15:44:07|0
0|0|0|1|0|0|ABC|15:44:07|0
0|0|0|0|0|0|ABC|15:44:07|0
0|1|0|0|0|1|ABC|15:44:07|0
```

Comment: Might be worth adding why using `for` is bad in this situation as it's not immediately obvious what the difference could be if you don't already know

Comment: @choroba: Why do you prefer a postfixed increment in `$counts{ $column_names[$i] }++`? It's highly unreadable.

Comment: @Borodin: Because of an old habit. Preincrement is probably also faster.

Comment: @choroba: I would hope that the difference is optimised out if the value of the expression isn't used, but far too many people use `$c++` when they really mean `++$c` just because of the name of the name of the language. Pre-increment is much quicker to understand, especially if the operand is a long expression, because it puts the "verb" first.

Comment: @choroba @Borodin Just BTW: `perl -MO=Deparse -e '$counts{ $column_names[$i] }++ if $columns[$i];'` outputs `++$counts{$column_names[$i]} if $columns[$i];` (and the optree shows that Perl indeed changes it to preinc)

Comment: Replaced postincrement with preincrement.